# GridView: How can I get rid of extra space from my GirdView object?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application for Android phones for Human vs. Human chess play over the internet. I was looking at some tutorials, to learn how to develop Android applications and found a very nice example of making galleries (it was a GridView usage example for making a gallery about dogs) and the idea came to draw the chess table using a GridView, because the example project also handled the point & click event and I intended to use the same event in the same way, but for a different purpose. The game works well (currently it's a hotseat version), however, I'm really frustrated by the fact that whenever I rotate the screen of the phone, my GridView gets hysterical and puts some empty space in my chess table between the columns. I realized that the cause of this is that the GridView's width is the same as its parent's and the GridView tries to fill its parent in with, but there should (and probably is) be a simple solution to get rid of this problem. However, after a full day of researching, I haven't found any clue to help me to make a perfect drawing about my chess table without a negative side effect in functionality.
The chess table looks fine if the phone is in Portrait mode, but in Landscape mode it's far from nice.
This is how I can decide whether we are in Portrait or Landscape mode:

```
((((MainActivity)mContext).getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()) < ((MainActivity)mContext).getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight())
```

In the main.xml file the GridView is defined in the following way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/gridview"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:numColumns="8"
              android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
              android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
              android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
              android:gravity="center"
              >
    </GridView>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

I appreciate any help with the problem and thank you for reading this.

Portrait: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f388b3ec64.png

Landscape: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?ee790603a2.png

Comment: On the off chance you read this--you said you figured out a solution.  Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: Lajos, could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 4):

A GridView probably isn't what you want here. GridView, like ListView, is for efficiently presenting scrolling, unbounded data sets. A chess board is neither. Populating a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) programmatically is probably what you want instead.

The reason your GridLayout doesn't seem to be honoring `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` is that since GridView is meant for displaying unbounded data where each item can have a different size, it doesn't trust that items have a uniform width that can be reasonably measured. (If an adapter has 10,000 items, should GridView measure all of them to determine the correct column width?)

If you're going to try to keep using GridView for this anyway (which you shouldn't), try setting an explicit value for `android:layout_width` rather than `wrap_content`. This will stop the GridView from expanding to fill the available space. You can also use alternate layouts for different screen orientations using the resource system as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). Alternatively you can disable landscape mode using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` on the activity tag in your manifest. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply solvable using the setPadding method of your GridView object.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your deep answer, it helped me to find the right answer.

Comment: I have the same problem as Lajos, but padding didn't help me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705330/gridview-and-excess-space-padding

Comment: Even I am having same problem described here but padding didn't help me.. so any one please suggest me solution to this issue.