# GridView and excess space padding

Tags: android, layout, gridview, padding, stretch

I have a problem with grid view layout on Android. I can't find solution to eliminate extra space in grid view. I tried a lot of things (numColumns, columnWidth, stretchMode, gravity) and advices (from StackOverflow), but nothing works correctly. I spent almost 8 hours with this problem. Here is a code of grid view:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/lookbook_gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="0px"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0px"

        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="160px"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:background="#000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons">
    </GridView>
```

I also tried to reduce extra space programically:

```
private void setGridview()
{  
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lookbook_gridview);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    int gridSize = display.getWidth();
    int count = gridSize / 160; // image has 160x160 px
    int colWidth = (gridSize / count) - PADDING;

    gridview.setColumnWidth(colWidth);
    gridview.setNumColumns(count);
}
```

But it works only on my HTC Desire (right), but on emulator (left) with the same display resolution and the same API version - it is not working.

[image]

Does somebody know, how to set images in gridview without any special padding or space to work successfully with all resolutions and devices?

Comment: See my answer in [this][1] thread, it may help you.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876861/removing-the-extra-padding-in-a-gridview-in-android/27321360#27321360

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To solve my problem I used this gridView:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyGrid" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" 
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:scrollingCache="true" 
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:clipChildren="true" 
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">
</GridView>
```

The most important thing is the `clipChildren` property.

Comment: is setting clipChildren necessary though? The docs say it defaults to true http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren