# How to reduce space in GridView using Android?

Tags: android, xml, grid

I am having the following xml code and i want to reduce the space in between the Cell.

**String Array**

```
String[] numbers = new String[] { 
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

**XML Code-:**

```
 <GridView

android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:numColumns="5"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="5dp"
android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
android:padding="0dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 </GridView>
```

I want to reduce the spaces in between the cells but i don't find the code or xml attribute for it. Please Suggest me how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

i think that links'll solve your problem

[Check this out](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode)

[And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106404/3214739)